# IIS configuration (ASP.NET Core Module v2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I'm trying to publish an application made in .net 5 on an IIS server.

Process carried out:

- IIS installation;
- Installation of **.NET Runtime 5.0.6** (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-5.0.6-windows-x64-installer);
- Installation of A**SP.NET Core Runtime 5.0.6** (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer);
- New Pool created with .Net version as'Unmanaged code';
- Creation and appointment of a new application in IIS;

Considerations:

- Analyzing this error in other posts, I noticed that the module **ASP.NET Core Module v2** that is pointed within the web.config of the project, and that really if access the modules of the IIS server is not available. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (Module image that should appear)

[Modules IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhzIq.png)

About installing **ASP.NET Core Runtime 5.0.6**, according to other posts should be available at: *'C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2'*, but even if the installation is done successfully is not found in this directory.

Is there a configuration/installation that should be done for .Net 5?

Comment: "according to other posts should be available at: 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2'", which posts then? They can be completely wrong, and you should always start with Microsoft official documentation.

Comment: Yes, I follow the official documentation. I added the links of the installers used.
The directory reference is just a note I made regarding other servers that contain net 5 in operation.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report as there might be something you missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to deploy an ASP.NET Core app to IIS, you need to first configure your environment accordingly by installing the [.NET hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer).

Please [read this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) for details.

It's not as straight forward as before the days of .NET Core. Pay attention to your publishing model as well as you can now deploy a fully standalone version or one that depends on .NET being installed in the machine.

Lastly, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) contains useful information on other things you may want to consider as well as troubleshooting.

Comment: That's the process I said I did. I'll try to add clearer to my question

Comment: @VanderneySouza trust me. I went through the same thing. Do yourself a favor and install the hosting bundle. You are probably installing components separately. That didn't work for me. MS has a tool just for this so use it. Lastly, even though they claim you can just use net start, don't do it. Restart your server.

Comment: As soon as possible I will try to reinstall and restart the server. And I talk about results

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. The strange thing is that I had already done the same process and had not worked.

Comment: @VanderneySouza I am glad I was able to help. :-)